# ST_Overlaps for 2 TIN geometries

Tags: postgis, tin

`ST_Overlaps`, `ST_Contains`, `ST_Touches`, `ST_Within` works for TIN with point data. But, when I try with 2 TIN it gives error. Could you please help me understand the reason for failure and how to fix it. I need comparisons only between TIN objects.

```
SELECT ST_Overlaps
('TIN Z (((0 0 0,0 0 0.5,0 0.5 0.5,0 0 0)),((0 0.5 0,0 0 0,0 0.5 0.5,0 0.5 0)))'::geometry,
 'POINT(0.5 0 0.5)'::geometry);

SELECT ST_Overlaps
('TIN Z (((0 0 0,0 0 0.5,0 0.5 0.5,0 0 0)),((0 0.5 0,0 0 0,0 0.5 0.5,0 0.5 0)))'::geometry, 
 'TIN Z (((0 0 0,0 0 0.5,0 0.5 0.5,0 0 0)),((0 0.5 0,1 1 1,1 0.5 0.5,0 0.5 0)))'::geometry);
```

> ERROR:  Unknown geometry type: 15 - Tin
>   CONTEXT:  SQL function
>   "st_overlaps" statement 1

-Note: `ST_3dIntersects` works with 2 TIN objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is something of a hack, but you can use a the replace function on the TIN Zs, convert those to POLYGON Zs, and then use ST_Dump to extract the individual triangles as polygons. For example:

```
WITH 
    tin (id, geom) AS (
       SELECT (ST_Dump(
                  ST_GeomFromText(
                     replace(
                        'TIN Z (((0 0 0,0 0 0.5,0 0.5 0.5,0 0 0)),
                        ((0 0.5 0,0 0 0,0 0.5 0.5,0 0.5 0)))'::text, 
                        'TIN Z', 'MULTIPOLYGON')))
               ).*), 
    tin1 (id, geom) AS (
        SELECT (ST_Dump(
                   ST_GeomFromText(
                     replace(
                         'TIN Z (((0 0 0,0 0 0.5,0 0.5 0.5,0 0 0)),
                          ((0 0.5 0,1 1 1,1 0.5 0.5,0 0.5 0)))'::text, 
                          'TIN Z', 'MULTIPOLYGON')))
                ).*)
 SELECT 
      a.id[0], 
      b.id[0], 
      ST_3dIntersects(a.geom, b.geom) 
    FROM tin a, tin1 b;
```

As there is no 3D equivalent of ST_Contains, you would have to ensure that your TINs are closed in 3D (ie, are solids) and use [ST_3DIntersection](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_3DIntersection.html) of of the two TINs and compare against [ST_Volume](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Volume.html) of each individual one.

Comment: Thanks John Powell. I will try this and see if the results are as expected. Also, could you please recommend any book/ source which has query examples like the one you mentioned. All the books/ sources that I have seen so far just explains the function with very simple query, like the one I wrote in this post. I have worked on complex SQL and PLSQL but I am very new to Spatial databases and couldn't write/ think of complex inner queries or joins. Any pointers are appreciated.

Comment: There is a section on 3D in [this book](https://www.packtpub.com/big-data-and-business-intelligence/postgis-cookbook), and the blog of one of the authors, has more examples of this nature.

Comment: Here is the [git source](https://github.com/smathermather/postgis-etc) I referred to above, with some of this TIN manipulation type code.